# Kompare-like tool that needs no kdelibs dependencies?

Tags: software-rec, diff

Are there any [Kompare](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/)-like tools without KDE dependencies? Can be Qt or GTK based.

[image: screenshot of Kompare]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). It depends on Python and some GTK libraries but not much else.

From its web page:

> Meld is a visual diff and merge tool targeted at developers. Meld helps you compare files, directories, and version controlled projects. It provides two- and three-way comparison of both files and directories, and has support for many popular version control systems.

[image: screenshot of meld]

Comment: A great tool, especially for the clarity of it when you diff three folders, which hopefully doesn't happen everyday but may be pretty complicated to do.

Answer (score 3):

When i want to do something like this i use `diff`:

`diff $file_1 $file_2 > result.diff`

You need only few minutes to learn the syntax of *result.diff* :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `vimdiff`. Vim lay-out, highlighted difference and vim editing.

Answer (score 1):

I like [tkdiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/) - it's unreasonably portable, since it has a history of maintainers over the years, and since it's been around for years, it's really mature.  Works well with RCS and CVS at least, so for code archeology, it's useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use [`diffuse`](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/), which works well under xubuntu.  Integration with SVN/CVS/Git/Mecurial/Bazaar.  Can be used as a mergetool, but call me old-fashioned, I don't really care for that functionality in a GUI.  Uses (py)gtk.